# Check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 10

Tags: mysql, syntax-error

## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 10

I faced this issue while creating a table for SQL 5.6. I do not where is the error

```
CREATE TABLE Name(
    ContactID CHAR(5),
    NamePrefix VARCHAR(8) NULL,
    MiddleName VARCHAR(35) NULL,
    NameSuffix VARCHAR(4) NULL,
    Nickname VARCHAR(35) NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (ContactID),
    FOREIGN KEY (ContactID)
);
```

I am using Infinity Free to host my SQL database

Comment: There's no `REFERENCES` clause for the foreign key constraint.

Comment: Did you try reading the MySQL documentation about creating tables with FOREIGN KEY constraints?